# Call a library in a HTML prompt on App Script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to call a function from a library in a HTML page but it doesn't work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <label for="champ1">Champ 1 :</label>
      <input type="text" name="champ1" id="champ1" required><br>
      <label for="champ2">Champ 2 :</label>
      <input type="text" name="champ2" id="champ2" required><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Valider">
    </form>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Récupérez les valeurs des champs champ1 et champ2
    var champ1 = document.getElementById("champ1").value;
    var champ2 = document.getElementById("champ2").value;
    
    // Exécutez votre fonction baseFinale avec les valeurs
  
      google.script.run.DatabaseposttreatmentMaster.coconexion(DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2);
      google.script.host.closeDialog();

    // Réinitialisez le formulaire
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've got the following message in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coconexion')
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>
```

How can i solve the problem ?

EDIT :

I try your method with an intermediate function :

```
function callFunctionByNameWithArguments(funcname,arguments) {
  DatabaseposttreatmentMaster[funcname].apply(DatabaseposttreatmentMaster,arguments);
}

function testFunk() {
  callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,2,25])
}
```

It's working very well in the GS code, like the "old" version :

```
function coconexion(){
  DatabaseposttreatmentMaster.coconexion(DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2);
}
```

But in the HTML code nothing happens, i call the function like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <label for="champ1">Champ 1 :</label>
      <input type="text" name="champ1" id="champ1" required><br>
      <label for="champ2">Champ 2 :</label>
      <input type="text" name="champ2" id="champ2" required><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Valider">
    </form>

<script>
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Récupérez les valeurs des champs champ1 et champ2
    var champ1 = document.getElementById("champ1").value;
    var champ2 = document.getElementById("champ2").value;
    
    // Exécutez votre fonction baseFinale avec les valeurs
  
      google.script.run.callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2]);
      google.script.host.closeDialog();

    // Réinitialisez le formulaire
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did a wrong thing in the HTML code ?

Comment: where does variable `google` come from?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand : google.run.script.DatabaseposttreatmentMaster ? it's the library which is installed on the app script project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling it by name through an intermediate function like this:

```
function callLibraryFunctionsByName(funcname) {
  libraryName[funcname]();
}
```

Handling Arguments:

Copy the following functions, paste and save and run testFunk the execution log is show below.

```
function callFunctionByNameWithArguments(funcname,arguments) {
  this[funcname].apply(this,arguments);
}

function funkToCall(A,B) {
  console.log(A);
  console.log(B)
}

function testFunk() {
  callFunctionByNameWithArguments('funkToCall',[1,2])
}

Execution log
9:46:14 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:46:15 AM  Info    1
9:46:15 AM  Info    2
9:46:16 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

If your executing a library call then change `this` to the library name

- [Learn more about apply,bind and call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) Note: this will take you to developer.mozilla.org

Comment: @FlipFlop Check server execution logs. What exactly do you expect to happen though?

Comment: @TheMaster if i'm using the Cooper 's method, i have a first message
 2267292534-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:165     POST https://docs.google.com/wardeninit?_reqid=53577&rt=j 404 (Not Found)
But i'm not sure if it's the problem, because the message appears when i click on the submenu, before i do anything.
My function is supposed to be writing "okay" in a specified cell by row and columns (champ1 and champ2)

Comment: @FlipFlop That's an irrelevant error. Check "server" execution logs - not client browser. Also, add `.withFailureHandler(e=>console.error(e))`

Comment: I get those all of the time.  I don't pay  any attention to them because they don't seem to interfere the getting the code to work.

Comment: @TheMaster i added `.withFailureHandler(e=>console.error(e))` and it's working.
But i have this message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withFailureHandler')
Maybe it's the way i added to the code ? 
`google.script.run.callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2]).withFailureHandler(e=>console.error(e));`
Also, if i read the doc about withFailureHandler(function), It seems to be that i have an exception in the code ? I'm sorry i'm a beginner in app script

Comment: @FlipFlop 1. Did you check server executions? - In script editor > Executions(the last icon in the left tab) 2. You add failure handler before the function call  `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(e=>console.error(e)).callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2]) `

Comment: @TheMaster if i wrote `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(e=>console.error(e)).callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2])` the script doesn't work anymore. When i check server executions, i don't have any errors but the function `callFunctionByNameWithArguments` doesn't appear in the log execution.
However, when the `withFailureHandler`is added after the function, i see `callFunctionByNameWithArguments` in the log execution, and the function is working. But the mistake about the Uncaught TypeError is still here

Comment: @FlipFlop I think you misread or mistimed the logs. This is the correct syntax `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(e=>console.error(e)).callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2])`. The other won't work. Btw, did you invite me to chat?

Comment: @TheMaster I confirm what i said before and it's even more strange i was thinking : whatever i add after the `google.script.run.callFunctionByNameWithArguments('coconexion',[DATABASE_POST_TREATMENT_ID,champ1,champ2])` , the script write in the cell i choose but i have an error message in the HTML console (not in the server log) and my  window doesn't close after the writing because of this mistake.
I created the same files and codes in another computer on another drive, it's working perfectly, so i'm confuse.

Comment: I found the problem : its `google.script.host.closeDialog();`
When i remove this line, it's working ! But why ? I also try `google.script.host.close` but it's the same issue...

Comment: Ok , i added  `withFailureHandler` to the `google.script.host.close` because `google.script.run` is asynchronous and now it's working perfectly ! Thanks so much for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Read the library documentation that you're trying to implement, there must be an installation page, normally it's from `npm install` if your project is using Node.js or maybe there is a CDN `https://cdnjs...` make sure to added in your HTML script tag

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.your-javascript-code.min.js"></script> <!-- Replace it with your actual cdn url -->
</body>
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, 
The library mentioned (Databaseposttreatmentmaster) is, in fact, another app script project where i created all my functions. I can use it in the gs code of the current project and all my functions are operating properly, because i load the Databaseposttreatmentlaster as a library in the Gs code.
Do i need to edit Databaseposttreatment as a web app, even if i load in th current appp script project ?